# What VBA code should i use to copy data from column A to F in Excel worksheet into another worksheet minus blank cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to copy data from a report into a new sheet with the cells arranged how i want them (unfortunately the original report can't be formatted!).

I've got the formatting down, however it's creating rows where the data has a 0.

I want the VBA code to copy the cells from Columns A:F to another worksheet. I've seen examples of how to do single columns but am too much of a novice to recreate the code for other columns (and I want it to look nice and neat!)

```
Sub copynoblanksA()
'
'

'
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, i As Long
Dim j As Long, N As Long, r1 As Range

    Set sh1 = Sheets("List1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet4")

N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1

For i = 1 To N
        Set r1 = sh1.Cells(i, "A")
        If r1.Value <> "" Then
            r1.Copy sh2.Cells(j, "A")
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the info, i've tried the above but it returns data where there is a 0, i want to condense the data into a more user friendly view

Answer (score 0):

For most of these simple issues, this is best practice:

- Go to the Developer tab then click on 'record macro' (give a name to the macro)
- Select the column you wish to copy, copy to the tab you wish to copy
- Go to Developer tab then click on 'stop recording'
- Go to the editor, look at the script, insert it in your code, and eventually adapt it with your variables.

to paste cells but not the empty ones you can use the code:

```
Range("A1:A20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=Sheets("newsheet").Range("A1")
```

Comment: thanks, i'm really looking for the code that stops cells with 0 value being copied. I'm thinking i might just have to suck eggs and concatenate it into one cell :(

Comment: ok even if this is quite a vulgar comment, I added and example of a copy/paste that removes blank cells if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now, a non-VBA solution:

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$8="0",ROW($B$1:$B$8),999999),ROW(A1))),"")

The first Index(A1:A8) if the range of data you want to move.  The B1:B8 in the If is your criteria range. (Aka the column you want to be 0). The ROW command needs to be 1:N, where N is how many rows you have in total. The last ROW needs to be where your data is, and needs to change as it's dragged down. This is an array formula, so you'll need to hit ctr+shift+enter